# Dynamically allocated array of dynamically allocated strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, dynamic

I'm learning C after graduation and trying to refresh old skills. I'm currently trying to make a dynamically allocated array that consist of dynamically allocated strings. Below is my code, I am trying to add an adjective to previously initialized array that has the first member as NULL. The last member should always be NULL.

```
char **addAdjective(char **array, const char *adjective)
{
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (*array != NULL){
        array++;
        count += 1;
    }
    array = (char**) realloc(*array, sizeof(*array) * (count+2));

    int adjectiveLength = strlen(adjective);
    array[count] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(const char)*(adjectiveLength + 1));        

    for (i = 0; i < adjectiveLength; i++){
        array[count][i] = adjective[i];
    }
    array[count][i+1] = '\0';


    array[count+1] = NULL;    

    return array;   
}
```

When I'm calling the above with:

```
adjectives = addAdjective(adjectives, "beautiful");
adjectives = addAdjective(adjectives, "ugly");
adjectives = addAdjective(adjectives, "sweet");
```

There seems to be something wrong as when I'm trying to print the array I get nothing..

What could be wrong?

EDIT:

Print function should be okay:

```
void printAdjectives(char **adjectives)
{
    if (!adjectives)
        return;
    while (*adjectives) {
        printf("%s  ", *adjectives);
        adjectives++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And initialization:

```
char **initAdjectives(void)
{
    char **adjectives = (char **)malloc (1 * sizeof(char *));

    *adjectives = NULL;    

    return adjectives;
}
```

Comment: You should include the print function too, there could be a bug there.

Comment: Also, how is `adjectives` initially allocated?

Answer (score 1):

```
array[count][i+1] = '\0';
```

ought to be

```
array[count][i] = '\0';
```

Or better

```
array[count][adjectiveLength] = '\0';
```

Notice that when the code reaches that line `i==adjectiveLength`.
You allocated `adjectiveLength+1` characters and writing to `i+1` is past the end of the allocated space.

I don't know if that's your only error but it is illegal.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your answer. Unfortunately it did not solve my problem :/